# Is there any faster way of synchronize the Drive from Colab

Tags: python, ffmpeg, subprocess, google-colaboratory, google-drive-realtime-api

I need to extract many frames of the videos of one dataset stored in Google Drive from colab code. I mounted drive with

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/gdrive')
```

I am generating and saving the frames with `ffmpeg` library calling a subprocess.

```
subprocess.call(["ffmpeg", "-i", src, dest])
```

or

```
subprocess.check_call(["ffmpeg", "-i", src, dest])
```

The files `.jpg` are uploaded in drive but not fast. And, at a certain point the synchronization stops, having executed the generation process on the whole dataset in colab.

Comment: How large are the images? What is the transfer rate you observe?

Comment: @BobSmith analizing the sequence of uploads in my drive, only 70 images per minute on average, each image of 3kb. Therefore, 210kb/min = 3.5kb/s. Approximately

Comment: Maybe, a forced synchronization command or waiting for synchronization occurs to continue generating images may prevent the synchronization stops before transfer all data. Does Anybody know a way to make some of them?